# Determine the order of an infinitesimal

Tags: calculus

Let x tend to 0. Determine the order of α(x) = sqrt(1 + x) - sqrt (1 - x) with respect to x.

My attempt: Let α(x) and β(x) be infinitesimals as x tends to 0. Recall that if lim α(x)/(β(x))^n=c, where 0<|c|<+∞,then the function α(x) is an infinitesimal of the nth order as compared with β(x) . Here α(x)= sqrt(1 + x) - sqrt (1 - x) and β(x)=x. Thus we compute: lim (sqrt(1 + x) - sqrt (1 - x)) / x^n Can't solve any further

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3440862/determine-the-order-of-an-infinitesimal-with-respect-to-x-when-x-0)

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$\alpha(x):=\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}={2x\over\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}\ ,$$
so that
$${\alpha(x)\over x^1}={2\over\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}\to1\qquad(x\to0)\ .$$
It follows that $\alpha(x)$ is "an infinitesimal of order $1$ when $x\to0$".

Answer (score 0):

If you use the binomial expansion or Taylor series, you should get
$$\alpha(x)=x+\frac{x^3}{8}+O\left(x^4\right)=x+O\left(x^3\right)$$